# Updating Old Thunderbird Plugin

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm looking to update the Mozilla Thunderbird plugin found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/additional-folder-views/). The current version was produced in 2007, and doesn't even allow thunderbird to install it. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of where to start, or maybe even point me in the direction of a plugin that does the same thing.

Comment: unless you have access to the source, it's going to be difficult to update the plugin. It'll be easier to just write your own with no source.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the knowledge for Thunderbird addons is located at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Thunderbird ; the addon you can download from addons.mozilla.org is a mere .zip file so you can definitely look at the source and modify it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment contains instructions to setup a development environment, which will allow you to catch errors and figure out why exactly the plugin no longer works.